# Regarding HTML - Using "|"

Tags: html, css

I am using a few of these "|" to separate different links on the website I'm coding, since it's separating links that are next to one another. Is there a chunk of code I can add directly to the CSS to do this?

"color all | #383838"

**Here's an example of what I am doing with my HTML:**

[Home](http://9385729notareallink010101.com) | [Page 1](http://9385729notareallink010101.coms)

^ I didn't use real links, but that is how it shows up on my site. (not in those colors though).... Here's the code I used to do this.

```
<p><a href="LINK HERE">Home</a> | <a href="LINK HERE">Page 1</a>
```

**Problem:** On my page, all of the text and links are one color. Having the "|" in the code in the HTML, it automatically turns the "|" the color as all other text and links. Can I added something within the CSS to make EVERY "|" another color?

Juhana's solution ended up working. HOWEVER, when I wrap it with < p > < / p > ....it all turns back to the same colors again...and I have to wrap it in < p > < / p > or it sits directly on top of the copyright footer... any ideas on how I can create a space so they are sitting on top of each other with no space (without having to add < p > < / p >)?

Ended up finding my own solution, using: < br / >

Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: can you put your html here?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Change the color of the `|` characters or create them using CSS?

Comment: I added the HTML code and example to my initial question, above.

Comment: It's still not clear what the actual problem is.

Comment: Problem: On my page, all of the text and links are one color. Having the "|" in the code in the HTML, it automatically turns the "|" the color as all other text and links. Can I added something within the CSS to make EVERY "|" another color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to style individual characters inside otherwise unmarked text. If the `|` characters are the only non-link text in the link group, wrap it in a div and style that. It won't affect the links' color.

```
<div class="links">
    <a href="LINK HERE">Home</a> | <a href="LINK HERE">Page 1</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.links {
    color: #383838;
}
```

Or if there's other text as well so wrapping the whole block isn't possible, wrap the individual characters:

```
<a href="LINK HERE">Home</a> <span class="separator">|</span> <a href="LINK HERE">Page 1</a>
```

Comment: Actually ^ your solution ended up working!!!!! HOWEVER, when I wrap it with < p > < / p> ....it all turns back to the same colors again...

Comment: And the problem is, I have to wrap it in < p > < / p > because if I don't , it sits right on top of the copyright footer.. any other ideas to help or how to put a space between them?

Comment: `<div class="links"><p>...` or just style the div so that it has margin and/or padding.

Comment: Or actually, I suppose the problem is that you have a CSS rule for `p` that overrides the div style. Use `.links p { ...` so the new rule is more specific.

Answer (score 3):

you can apply this css : `border-right :solid 1px #000000;` to the tag around the anchor links.

Answer (score 3):

Use unordered list to place links and then add | like that:

```
li:after {
    content: '|';
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by unordered list to place the links? (Sorry, just started programming yesterday)

Answer (score 1):

MarcinJuraszek is pretty right, I would do the same.
But i would also add:

```
li:last-child:after {
   content: '';
}
```

To remove the line after the last link

Comment: Recommend using `li:before` and `li:first-child:before` for IE8 support (see [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/#link6), IE8 doesn't support the `:last-child` pseudo-selector).

Answer (score 0):

Give `li` elements `border-right:1px solid black` and then to the last li child :

```
li:last-child{border-right:none;}
```

For IE8 compatibility, check [**selectivizr**](http://selectivizr.com/)

Dowload selectivizr and include it in your project then include this code in head tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[JS library]"></script>
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="selectivizr.js"></script>
   <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="[fallback css]" /></noscript>
<![endif]-->
```